# Issues rendering text into json response in rails controlelr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm trying to return json from my method in my app

Heres what i have

```
 doc.css(".secondary-text").each do |t|
   price1 = t.text
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json  { render :json => {:testing => price1}}
    end
 end
```

However i'm getting `DoubleRenderError`. Whats returned is this:

```
(Â£28.50 Ticket + Â£4.00 Fees)
(Â£35.00 Ticket + Â£5.25 Fees)
(Â£22.50 Ticket + Â£3.50 Fees)
(Â£35.00 Ticket + Â£5.25 Fees)
(Â£22.50 Ticket + Â£3.50 Fees)
```

Is it because its inside the each method?

Thanks

Comment: _Is it because its inside the each method?_ - yes

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's because you use `render` as many times as many objects are present in `doc.css(".secondary-text")`. `Render` can be used only once per scope.

If you want to render whole collection, you should do something like that:

```
collection = doc.css(".secondary-text").each.inject([]) do |collection, t|
  collection << t.text
  collection
end

respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: { collection: collection } }
end
```